# to remove special characters from mailx output

Tags: unix, mailx

I've a code that mails the output of a command:

```
File2=`ls -lrt ABC.LOG* |grep "Aug 24" |awk '{print $9}'`
File3=`ls -lrt abc.LOG* |grep "Aug 24" |awk '{print $9}'`

echo "Below are logs : \n \n `tail $File2`  \n \n `tail $File3`" |mailx -s "Deatils" xyz@abc.com
```

But in the output I'm getting some special characters like "[0m" and "[31m".
I need to understand what are these characters and how can I get rid of it?

Below is the output:

```
Details found. file available is filex_23647.csv
 [0m
duration : 13 (seconds)
 [31m
------ Process finished ------[0m
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Those appear to be [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 1):

Those sequences are ANSI color codes.  They could be coming from `ls`
or `grep`.  Maybe you have aliases for them that are using colors.  To
be explicit you can pass them both the `--color=never` option.

```
ls --color=never ... | grep --color=never ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm getting error: `grep: illegal option -- -
grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- o`

Comment: got one answer: `perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g'`